# Is there any widget in tkinter or other GUI modules to make a pie menu that overlays over any program in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Basically, I'm trying to find a GUI widget (from any gui module) that works like a pie menu, but more importantly that is windowless and has transparent background... I supposed it can be mocked using the "canvas" widget.

I saw this [this](http://piemenu.sourceforge.net/), but it's really old... And haven't seen anything like it. I remember making a mockup concept a long time ago using AutoHotkey and [WinSetRegion](https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/commands/WinSetRegion.htm) and its gui's canvas... It was really crude though.

I need something like blender's pie menus, to select a macro (name) from a selection, so it's pretty much hold mouse and release when it's over the choice you want. Basically I want to have a canvas/pie-menu widget with no window so it works as a pop-up with no background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed create a pie menu with transparent background using `canvas`. Here is a sample to create a basic layout:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root,bg="white",bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
circle = canvas.create_oval(5,5,250,250,outline="black",fill="green")
circle2 = canvas.create_oval(80,80,180,180,outline="black",fill="white")
txt = canvas.create_text(170, 50, text='Command 1',angle=48,tag="command1")
canvas.tag_bind("command1", "<Button-1>",lambda e:print ("Hi i am command 1"))
canvas.pack()

root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")
root.overrideredirect(True)

root.mainloop()
```

Simply add additional polygons on the canvas and attach callbacks to them.

Comment: You are on windows @Henry; is there a way to make this work on a mac?

Comment: Sadly I don't have much knowledge on working this on a mac. Happy to see a mac solution for this as well.